# Reactjs, change the favicon in componentDidMount

Tags: html, reactjs, href, favicon

I want to change the favicon of the Reacjs application according to some properties. I already have saved the icons in `public` folder but cannot find a way to give the path as `href` to a newly created element.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { project } = this.props.rootStore!;
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    const oldLink = document.getElementById('favicon');
    link.id = 'favicon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = // here I tried the following string literals
    if (oldLink) {
      document.head.removeChild(oldLink);
    }
    document.head.appendChild(link);
  }

link.href='%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/images/' + project.id + '/favicon.ico';
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

link.href = `%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/images/${project.id}/favicon.ico`;
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

link.href = '%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/images/${project.id}/favicon.ico';
// GET http://localhost:3000/demo/category/showroom/%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/images/$%7Bproject.id%7D/favicon.ico 400 (Bad Request)
```

Now my question can be first: what is the best way to change the favicon in Reacjs (I searched a lot but did not find any answer).
second: how should I define the `href`.

Comment: The error `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` means that `project` is undefined. The reason why it's undefined is not shown.

Comment: @estus  :D yes, thanks. I was in such an angry mood that why the path does not work, did not get the `id` is related to project object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no best way to do this. React offers no functionality to deal with existing DOM elements outside the application. This should be done in React as it would be done in vanilla JavaScript:

```
let link = document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]') ||
  document.querySelector('link[rel="icon"]');

if (!link) {
    link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = 'favicon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}

link.href = `/assets/images/${id}/favicon.ico`;
```

`href` should preferably contain absolute path or URL to provide correct icon location regardless of base URL.

Comment: Property `rel` does not exist on type `Element`
Property 'href' does not exist on type 'Element'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and my previous comment was a TypeScript type error

Comment: You're welcome. The question doesn't mention that you use TS. Then `link` should be typed as `HTMLLinkElement`.

Answer (score 4):

One React-y way to do this is using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

With that library you can change the elements inside the `<head>`

Eg.

```js
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

...

<Helmet>
  <title>ABC</title>
  <meta name="ABC" content: "ABC" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" sizes="16x16" />
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install react-meta-tags --save
```

https://github.com/s-yadav/react-meta-tags

Very happy with this in my projects. `Helmet` is another option.

```
import React from 'react';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

class Component1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <MetaTags>
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Some description." />
            <meta property="og:title" content="MyApp" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg" />
          </MetaTags>
          <div className="content"> Some Content </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `react-helmet` is significantly more popular